# Resource for an explanation of Sample size calculation when $\alpha$, Power and Effect Size for t-Test are given

Tags: t-test, sample-size, effect-size, statistical-power

For a simple z-Test or t-Test (one-sample or two-independent-sample with $n_1 = n_2$ and equal variance) I want to calculate the required sample size $n$ when the significance level $\alpha$, power and effect size are given.

Can someone point me to a resource where this is explained (not only software or a table with given values)? This would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to significance level $\alpha$ and target power, you will need an estimated population standard deviation, and an 'effect size' (difference between null and alternative values of $\mu).$

Many statistical software packages have 'power and sample size' procedures (e.g., R and Minitab, for sure). And there are on-line 'sample size calculators' of various degrees of trustworthyness.

Here is output from Minitab, for which I provided $\alpha, \sigma,$and target powers .8 and .9:

Power and Sample Size

```
2-Sample t Test

Testing mean 1 = mean 2 (versus ≠)
Calculating power for mean 1 = mean 2 + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 4.5


            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
         5      14     0.8      0.807761
         5      19     0.9      0.914970

The sample size is for each group.
```

[image]

*Notes:* Power of a t test requires computing probabilities and quantiles  of non-central t distributions. Power for z tests can be found using printed standard normal tables; sonm intermediate-level applied statistics books have formulas (Ott & Longnecker, for sure), otherwise you can use the definition of power,

;